# How to SSH to circleci@xxx and access to the actual build container?

Tags: ssh, circleci

### Summery

I"m gonna access a build container using SSH on CircleCI 2.0.
I can SSH to the running job. But user is not circleci@xxx.
How to SSH to circleci@xxx and access to the actual build container?

### What I've tried

1. set SSH key to GitHub

```
❯ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi jpskgc! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

2. return job with SSH
3. SSH to the running job
   [image]
4. see usr is root@xxx, not circleci@xxx
   [image]

Comment: Can you use sudo to switch users after you login as root@xxx ?  For example run ```sudo su - circleci```

Comment: Thanks for reply. No. `-bash: sudo: command not found` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from circleci official.

```
Hi,

Thanks for reaching out to us.

The container will use the default user for the image. 
In this case, you are using the ubuntu:18.04 image which defaults to root. 
This is because the ubuntu:18.04 is not a dedicated CircleCI convenience image.

You can check who the user is during a run by adding - run: whoami - in this instance it will return root.

The equivalent CircleCI image would be cimg/base:stable-18.04. 
You can find out more information about this image here: 
https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/base

As long as you SSH in via the details provided in the SSH step, 
you will be accessing the container in the same way as the job is run.

Adam

Senior Support Engineer @ CircleCI
```

In my case, working directory is set at /go/src/mordpress-simulation

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: /go/src/mordpress-simulation
```

So, after cd  /go/src/mordpress-simulation, I reach the actual contents.

[image]